# Synonym request for [subclasses] --> [subclass]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

Can you please make the [subclasses](/questions/tagged/subclasses) tag a synonym of the [subclass](/questions/tagged/subclass) tag? Both tags have exactly the same tag wiki summary, and the only difference between what they mean is in popularity, [subclass](/questions/tagged/subclass) being more popular. I doubt there is any reason to have both.